# Is there a way to have an opportunistically shared SSH connection without blocking the local TTY session?

Tags: systemd, openssh, connection-sharing

In my `~/.ssh/config`, I have the `ControlMaster auto` setting enabled. It works pretty well for me, but there is one behaviour that irritates me that I’d like to eliminate.

Let’s say I have two terminal emulator windows A and B. In window A, I invoke `ssh` to connect to a remote host, then I do the same in window B. Next, I type `exit` in window A to close the session. Although I have disconnected, the `ssh` process in window A does not exit to the local session because it has to wait for the process in window B to end its remote session as well: it has to keep the control socket running.

I would rather have it so that when I disconnect in window A, I am immediately returned to the original local session from which I invoked `ssh`, while the session in window B keeps running. You may ask: well, which process should manage the control socket then? Ideally, I’d like it to be a dedicated third process running under the supervision of the user systemd instance, that automatically disconnects when there are no more sessions running. But I’d also accept a more hacky approach with a lingering background process.

And I would rather avoid launching the control socket master manually. It should start automatically as soon as I open the first session.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: I honestly have never seen that behaviour, it just works out of the box. Maybe because I have `ControlPersist` set to a timeout value, so it knows from the start that it needs to fork?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz `ControlPersist` is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A command such as

```
ssh -f -N remote_host
```

will create an `ssh` session to the remote host but not run a command (`-N`) and background itself (`-f`).  This command could be used as the master.

If you want to tunnel things like X then this could also be done on this command

```
ssh -X -f -N remote_host
```

If you find the idle session disconnecting (e.g. because of NAT timeouts) then adding something like

```
-o ServerAliveInterval=30
```

(or equivalent in your `config` file) will try to keep the session active.

Comment: Yes, but I don’t want to run a separate command for that. I want it to automatically start as soon as I open the first session.